# Statistics:Power Question Update

Tags: self-study, statistical-power

I have already asked this question but I did not initially give out all the details on the question, like the question being a multiple choice question.

You manufacture and sell a iron rod whose electrical conductivity is supposed to be 10.1.
You plan to make 6 measurements of the conductivity of a rod you plan to sell. You know that the standard deviation of your measurements is σ=0.1. If the product meets specifications, the mean of many measurements will be 10.1.

You will therefore test

H0:μ=10.1
Ha:μ≠10.1

The question is:

Explain why the test you plan will not adequately protect you against selling a rod with conductivity 10.15.

The possible answers are: 
A.  Because the probability of mistakenly concluding that μ = 10.15 when the product is unsuitable is too high.
B.  Because the probability of mistakenly concluding that μ = 10.15 when the product is suitable is too high. 
C.  Because the probability of mistakenly concluding that μ = 10.15 when actually μ ≠ 10.15 is too high. 
D.  Because the power of a test against the alternative μ = 10.15 is only a probability, not a certainty.

I believe the answer is Because the probability of mistakenly concluding that μ=10.15 when the product is suitable is too high because the power is 0.24 and that means there is a much greater chance that the rod is not going to eliminate the null hypothesis (0.76).

Also what is the difference if I increase the sample size to more than six.

Am I right or wrong? Or is it one of the other ones.

Thanks everyone